# Is it possible to get an airline to compensate lost incidental costs?

Tags: airlines, delays, compensation, disputes

We originally booked a flight with an overnight stop. We also booked a hotel in advance which was refundable until the day before our flight.

The morning of the flight everything was marked on time but by the time we got to the airport they told us our first leg was late and we would not make our first connection, so they re-routed us via another city and we had to spend the night there instead of where we already had the hotel.

We lost the cost of an moderately expensive hotel which I complained about. The airline responded that it is not *industry policy* to pay for incidental losses but gave us some points, roughly worth half of the hotel costs if used before they expire, of course.

Are we actually entitled to more? Is there any way to get better compensation?

Comment: What you are "entitled" to would normally be a question of law, and each country has its own law.  In what countries were your origin / stopover / destination?  What airline were you using?

Comment: Sounds like the kind of thing you should be claiming on your travel insurace

Comment: Not sure I understand the actual situation. How many flights were involved? How could you have not made the connection if you had an overnight stop? What this overnight stop an actual stop-over?

Comment: We had 3 flights: 1h, then 3 hours, overnight, then 4 hours. The 1h flight was delayed to arrived after the 3 hour flight left, so we slept there (1AM arrival) and did both the 3 and 4 hour flights the next day, starting at 5 AM.  This was quite an ordeal for our little girl which is why we had chosen such schedule in the first place.

Comment: @Gagravarr - Flying AA from Canada to Ecuador via the USA. Definitely will try with travel insurance too, we did have some.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As CHX pointed out, you had a contract with the airline to go from A to B and as long as they got you to B more or less when you originally were scheduled to arrive, then they have fulfilled their obligation. If you arrived appreciably later than originally scheduled, then you may have cause for compensation.

The airline is not responsible for the original hotel booking, as you accepted that original flight routing knowing full well there was an overnight stop during which you could sit in the airport or book your own hotel.  You choose the later.

The airline did provide accommodations in the new city because you were involuntarily re-routed due to delayed flights.  That is the breadth of their responsibility for the overnight layover.

Can you get better compensation?  Maybe, but if you have already accepted the points they offered, then renegotiation is not likely.  If not try a polite letter with facts and figures not complaints and accusations.

Comment: This and the other answer bring an interesting point: What is the contract with the airline exactly? I booked AA via Expedia and had certainly at least 50 flights to choose from. We did not choose the cheapest but the most convenient which meant two 4 hour days of flights with no early departures.  We ended up with 1 hour flight on day one, arriving at 1 AM and 7 hours the next day, departing at 5. Our daughter was so tired she was crying and very nice gentlemen took pity on us and brought us to a local hotel since the transport which the airline referred us to had not shown up for a while.

Comment: @Itai - Airlines post their "Contract of Carriage" on their websites, available for you to read (though not always easily found).  Because you booked through Expedia you are also effected by their booking terms and conditions (this applies primarily to the booking payment process not the flights, with a waiver that they are not responsible for anything during the flights).

Answer (score 2):

You have made a contract with the airline to transport you from A to B. Going through C was not part of the contract. It never is. They already did more than they are obliged to.

Also, did they pay you for the hotel where you got rerouted through? If so, then you paid for a hotel night, you got a hotel night, some miles and ... that's it. Perhaps of a lesser quality hotel night but still. Now, if they didn't pay for that hotel then there's something to talk about.

Comment: Not sure I agree with you. Given that there was a stop-over, this is really a trip from A to C then a trip from C to B. But in any case, whatever compensation may be due is based on the countries involved and the specifics of the itinerary.

Comment: That's a layover and not a stopover though. If the OP booked it as a stopover then this couldn't have happened but I'd bet anything it would have been much, much more expensive.